# Exception handling for class hierarchies

Tags: c++

When I talk about exception handling for classes, I am not really sure if I understood the exceptions really well. One grey area which I can find is to handle exceptions for class hierarchies. For e.g.

```
#include<iostream>
class B {
  public:
    B() {
      std::cout << "B ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~B() {
      std::cout << "B dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class D : public B {
  public:
    D() {
      std::cout << "D ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~D() {
      std::cout << "D dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  try {
    D d;
    throw d;
  } catch (D &d) {
    std::cout << "Derived caught" << std::endl;
  } catch (B &b) {
    std::cout << "Base caught" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This actually prints :

```
B ctor
D ctor
D dtor
B dtor
Derived caught
D dtor
B dtor
D dtor
B dtor
```

I did not understand why and what should I do to overcome this in case it is not encouraged.

Comment: Try adding traces for your copy constructors too.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4fe1cb7b5f28d17  I get just one set of dtors after the exception is caught, as expected.

Comment: I only get a single `D dtor B dtor` at the end (after `Derived caught`) with Visual Studio 2015. Note that there is a move construction that occurs here, accounting for the remaining destructor call.

Comment: I got two. I am using : 

`gcc version 4.4.7 20120313`

Comment: What are you even asking about? Overcome what? In case WHAT is not encouraged?